# select with variable in PostgreSQL using python

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

I'm tring to run select query in python where an id = to a number in a variable.

the following statement works from numbers 1 to 9

```
cur.execute("SELECT ex_id FROM live_orders WHERE lc_id = %s",lc_id)
```

any number more than or equal to 10 gives the following error

> TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing in a tuple or list. Try this:

```
cur.execute("SELECT ex_id FROM live_orders WHERE lc_id = %s",[lc_id])
```

or this:

```
cur.execute("SELECT ex_id FROM live_orders WHERE lc_id = %s",(lc_id,))
```